# Install Metro 2.0 on Glassfish 4

Tags: java, glassfish-4, java-metro-framework

I uninstalled metro newer version from glassfish 4 and tried to install metro 2.0.
But i could not see 2.0 version under pkg -fa metro command.
How can i install metro 2.0 in glassfish 4. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Metro 2.0 will work with Glassfish 4, anyway, quoting [Metro Project Web Site](https://metro.java.net/2.0/):

> In case you don't have an internet access or want to experiment with an unofficial build or release of Metro not available on the official GlassFish v3 update center, you may try the experimental standalone GlassFish v3 installer. To stop GlassFish v3 instance, install Metro 2.0 using the standalone installer on top of it and restart the GlassFish v3 instance, execute the following commands:

```
asadmin stop-domain <domain-name>
ant -Das.home=<GF_INSTALL_DIR> -f <METRO_INSTALL_DIR>/metro-on-glassfish-v3.xml install
asadmin start-domain <domain-name>
```

It is worth a shot since for GlassFish 4 and Metro 2.3, the standalone ant based installs are [still available](https://metro.java.net/2.3/), and the `ant` file is still called `metro-on-glassfish-v3.xml`.